# How to signal expensive vs cheap template parameters?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, type-traits

I have working code for a simple `bi_map`, a bi-directional map class for storing associated key-value pairs in both directions.  My current usage is, `NID` is some kind of numerical-id or enumeration, while `OBJ` is an expensive non-copyable class object.

Recently, I've noticed that I also have need for `bi_map<NID,std::string>`, `std::string` is a cheap `OBJ` that should really just be copied.

*What is the right way to generalize the code below so that user can signal whether something is expensive (I want to use pointers/references) or cheap (I want to copy everything by value), so that I can use the proper implementation?*

**CODE**

```
template<typename NID,typename OBJ>
class bi_map
{
  std::map<NID,OBJ*>        m_nid_2_ptr;
  std::map<OBJ const*,NID>  m_ptr_2_nid;

public:
  void insert( NID nid, OBJ& obj )
  {
    m_nid_2_ptr.insert( std::make_pair( nid, &obj ));
    m_ptr_2_nid.insert( std::make_pair( &obj, nid ));
  }

  NID operator[]( OBJ const& obj ) const
  {
    return m_ptr_2_nid.at( &obj );
  }
  OBJ const& operator[]( NID nid ) const
  {
    return *(m_nid_2_ptr.at( nid ));
  }

  using pairs_cb = std::function<void(NID,OBJ const&)>;
  void pairs( pairs_cb cb ) const
  {
    for( const auto& p : m_nid_2_ptr )
      cb( p.first, *p.second );
  }
  size_t size() const { return m_nid_2_ptr.size(); }
};
```

Comment: template<typename NID, typename OBJ, bool cheap> ?

Comment: Make it copy by default. Use `bi_map<..., unique_ptr<myobj> >` for expensive copies? (or some other wrapper type which keeps track of a pointer)

Comment: @Pubby +1 I just tried a simple, thin `my_namespace::ref<>` copyable wrapper and it works GREAT.  Not only is it useful for my `bi_map<>`, but I can use it anytime I need to store a reference in any value-based (STL) container.  Best of all, it is excellent separation-of-concerns: I can keep all my containers value-based, resulting in much simpler, easier-to-maintain code.  THANKS!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, there are multiple options and I guess, there is no one right answer. So, let's try to find something which works for *you*. You said you'd like to distinguish between cheap and expensive types. The most important design choice is the **interface**. You could use:

1) Specialize the template for pointers, having the *explicit clue* in the inteface that you are using a cheap type:

```
bi_map< int, std::string* > bi_map_1; // note * is to flag std::string as cheap
bi_map< int, ExpensiveObject > bi_map_2; // no *, thus using heavy implementation
```

which is implemented like this:

```
template< typename NID, typename OBJ >
struct bi_map
{
    // implementation for expensive objects, use OBJ* or std::shared_ptr<OBJ>
};

// specialize of the second parameter is a pointer
template< typename NID, typename OBJ >
struct bi_map< NID, OBJ* >
{
    // implementation for cheap objects, store a copy, i.e., use OBJ
};
```

of course you could also use `&` instead of `*` to flag the types if you find that more readable.

2) If you *don't* want the cheap/expensive separation to show up in the interface, i.e., if you want

```
bi_map< int, std::string > bi_map_1; // no *
bi_map< int, ExpensiveObject > bi_map_2; // no *
```

you need something different. One solution would be adding a defaulted template parameter:

```
template< typename >
struct is_expensive_for_bi_map : std::false_type {};

template< typename IND, typename OBJ, bool = is_expensive_for_bi_map< OBJ >::value >
struct bi_map
{
    // implementation for expensive objects, use OBJ* or std::shared_ptr<OBJ>
};

template< typename NID, typename OBJ >
struct bi_map< NID, OBJ, false >
{
    // implementation for cheap objects, store a copy, i.e., use OBJ
};
```

and for each type that you consider expensive, you add

```
template<>
struct is_expensive_for_bi_map< ExpensiveObject > : std::true_type {};
```

If expensive should be the default, just reverse the names and adapt the rest, should be easy enough.

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
template<typename T>
struct notExpensive {
  static const bool value = FALSE;
  typedef T REF;
  static T& ref(T& x) { return x; }
  static T& deref(T& x) { return x; }
};
template<typename T>
struct isExpensive {
  static const bool value = TRUE;
  typedef T* REF;
  static T* ref(T& x) { return &x; }
  static T deref(T* x) { return x; }
};
template<typename T>
struct expensiveP : public notExpensive<T> {};

// List of expensive types:
template<> struct expensiveP<ExpensiveObject> : public isExpensive<T> {};
```

Then fill BiMap with expensiveP calls.